# Multi-Object Report without APEX?

Tags: apex, visualforce, joined-reports

I created the attached report via a custom Controller, but now I have to recreate it without using APEX since my client won't pay for anything except Contact Manager edition.  Columns 1,2,5 and 7 come from the Account object.  Columns 3,4,6,8,9 come from Contact and the last column comes from User object.

Any suggestions on how to do this without any APEX code?

[image: Report]

Comment: Which edition is it in this list? http://www.salesforce.com/crm/editions-pricing.jsp

Comment: I'm thinking that this could be a list view, with some calcs - but I need to see if your edition can handle calcs

Comment: Key here would be formula field to bring in the values from the disjoined objects. (I.e. a formula to populate the last column from the report on the contact object.) Then you could use list views or reports.....In the negative, managing a lot of formula fields has its own implications

Comment: The screenshot is from Developer Edition, where I did the initial development of the app.  This client only wants Contact Manager, but I can't install the custom Controller I built since that edition doesn't support any APEX classes.  I even wrote a JS implementation, but it doesn't work either since Contact Manager edition doesn't support API calls.  @Eric - any advice on how to use formulas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reorganize a few fields so that I could recreate this using a standard report.  Thanks @Eric for causing me to go back to the standard report writer and look for creative solutions.